# Noise Floor when receiving Es'hail 2

Tags: satellites, noise

I'm currently trying to receive the Es'hail 2 satellite using a standard TV LNB, 60cm dish and RTL-SDR. My dish is slightly offset by 2 degrees, and my SNR is only about 15dB unfortunately.

My main issue is that there is a lot of noise. I can't figure out if the noise is coming from my LNB, or if it's due to a "hump" I think is coming from the satellite (which I think is just noise).

I am using RG6 coax, but the issue isn't really improved by reducing this to as little as 4m.

Amplifying the signal from the LNB just increases the noise also, so the SNR stays about the same.

Could someone please provide me some advice on what to expect, noise wise, from this satellite based on their experience? Do I just have a low quality LNB, or is the signal just weak due to my offset dish/size of dish.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have selected the right polarization?  Are you using the stock TCXO?  Maybe you could provide some more detail about your LNB.